# How to use CountDownTimer with floats

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I'd like to have milsec as the duration of the CountDownTimer if possible, what are the ways of doing it?

```
MuteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {

float seconds = Float.parseFloat(inputSeconds.getText().toString()); 
float milsec = seconds * 1000;

        new CountDownTimer(milsec, 1000) {
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    inputSeconds.setText("seconds remaining: " + 
millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                    inputMinutes.setText("Minutes remaining:" + 
millisUntilFinished / 6000);
}

 public void onFinish() {

 inputSeconds.setText("Unmuted");strong text
 }
 }.start();
 }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I converted the float into a long using

```
long milsec = (long) (seconds * 1000);
```

now it works

Comment: Maybe try that before asking on SO?